# should I see all the new added files at my svn at my server repository?

Tags: linux, svn

I created a new project in `svn svnadmin create /myrepo` in my server, with my client I did a checkout and add new files, later a commit, so, if I make a checkout from another computer I get the recently added files, which is perfect, but at my folder /myrepo still is no file, all the new files that were added from my client are not visible there, I know they implement many algoritms to take the version control, my question is, should I be able to see all the new files added from /myrepo in my server, without need to make a checkout with a client or something like that??

I want to know where my files are saved at my server,
Thanks

Comment: `/myrepo` is just a repository. I doubt you should see any files as you see it when you checkout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  The files are stored in the repository you created, but in a specialized database.  If you go to `myrepo` and look in the db folder, you'll see that there are revision files stored there.  Those files contain the structure and data of the repository at specific instances in time.  The [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.basics.html) has some information on the structure.  You can also look at the documentation in the actual Subversion repository [about the structure](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure) used to store the data.